# What is not thread safe about this function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I have this function that takes a string, and gets the text in between 2 given delimiters/texts.

```
std::vector<std::string> StandardFunctions::split_given_string_two_delimiters(const std::string& str, const std::string& start_delimiter, const std::string& end_delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    std::string::size_type start = 0, end;
    while ((start = str.find(start_delimiter, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        start += start_delimiter.size();
        if ((end = str.find(end_delimiter, start)) == std::string::npos) {
            break;
        }
        split_vector.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + end_delimiter.size();
    }
    return split_vector;
}
```

I don't see any modification/writing to a global variable taking place. Each thread has their own strings that are passed to the function as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think the function is not safe? Please describe the problem. Also, if there is a problem, you'll need to show the code that is most likely causing the issue, which is the multi-threaded code. Add a [mre] to show that.

Comment: The only thing that is potentially thread-unsafe about this code is, because the input strings are passed in by references, if the input strings are freed by another thread while this function is running, then bad things will happen.  For example, if the function is passed strings that are members of an object, and the object is freed.